# Deploy custom site on Azure VM (LAMP)

Tags: laravel, azure, azure-web-app-service, lamp

I am trying to learn how to move an application from on-prem to Cloud (Azure). I have an existing application (PHP, Laravel, MySQL) which is hosted on IIS. Following [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/tutorial-lamp-stack) tutorial, I was able to create a VM and install LAMP stack on the VM. The last part of the article uses a Wordpress app. But I would like to use the existing custom app I have built. It resides in a repository on Azure DevOps (formerly known as VSTS).

How do I deploy my web app on to the new VM ? I still don't fully understand the infrastructure but I would to learn through this POC.

Comment: You do the same that you have done in the on-premise to deploy your own application in the VM.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have already installed the below dependency and your VM is up and running.

- Create an Ubuntu VM (the 'L' in the LAMP stack)
- Open port 80 for web traffic
- Install Apache, MySQL, and PHP
- Verify installation and configuration
- Install WordPress on the LAMP server

After this you can actually use Azure devops CI feature to deploy your custom website in the azure vm like you are doing it in on-prem.

If you have some script to deploy, you can create a Azure devops CI/CD pipeline and call the script to deploy it. It has a direct feature to deploy it from code repository.

Azure DevOps Projects presents a simplified experience where you can bring your existing code and Git repo or choose a sample application to create a continuous integration (CI) and continuous delivery (CD) pipeline to Azure.

**DevOps Projects also:**

- Automatically creates Azure resources, such as a new Azure virtual machine (VM).
- Creates and configures a release pipeline in Azure DevOps that includes a build pipeline for CI.
- Sets up a release pipeline for CD.

Hope it helps.